# How can I move my bootstrap carousel next button back into the screen?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

Hi I am a newbie in html, css, bs and js but I am trying hard to learn. After overcoming many obstacles, I managed to create a working carousel item from bs on my site, however, the next button is out of screen. I tried inspecting element and found that the position was set to absolute so i tried changing it to all the other positions available but that made no difference. Furthermore, my carousel item was placed inside a
    
And the height and width of that .box was set to 100% and 100%. Yet, the next arrow was outside this box and all the way on the left. Some please help

My code is here:

```
<div class="box">
    <section class="colored-section" id="testimonials">
      <div id="testimonial-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="false">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active container-fluid">
                <h4 class="testimonial-text">Hello world</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item container-fluid">
                <h4 class="testimonial-text">Hello world again</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item container-fluid">
                <h4 class="testimonial-text">Hello world again and again</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev carousel-item" href="#testimonial-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span></a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next carousel-item" href="#testimonial-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span></a>
      </div>
    </section>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `.carousel-item` class from both of the buttons which are used to navigate the slider. Basically `.carousel-item` class specifies the content of each slide, simply put this class denotes an individual slide element in bootstap 4 carousel.
Hope it helps !

Comment: Pleased to help !

Answer (score 0):

In order to bring back the next button, I have changed the following:

1. Remove the `container-fluid` class.
2. For the `<a>` tag, remove the `carousel-item` class.

```css
body {
  background-color: tomato !important;
}

h4 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="box">
  <section class="colored-section" id="testimonials">
    <div id="testimonial-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="false">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <h4 class="testimonial-text">Hello world</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <h4 class="testimonial-text">Hello world again</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item ">
          <h4 class="testimonial-text">Hello world again and again</h4>
        </div>
      </div>

      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#testimonial-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span></a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#testimonial-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span></a>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I did 2 and it works! But if i remove container-fluid, then my text moves and gets aligned to the left so I didn't stick with that. Thank you again!

Comment: Glad to help. I aligned the `<h4>` to center with CSS. Btw, just stick with what works for you.